# warning: pointer/integer type mismatch in conditional expression

Tags: c, pointers

Following code is throwing

> "warning: pointer/integer type mismatch in conditional expression".

How could I solve this?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *str = "Error";
    char *sch_str="pqrs";
    int i=1;

    if (i >= 0)
            str = (sch_str[i] != NULL) ? sch_str[i] : "Unknown";


    printf("%c\n",sch_str[i]);
    printf("%s\n",str);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operands of the ternary operator must be convertible to the variable you're assigning it to.

```
char tmp[2] = { sch_str[i], '\0' };
str = (sch_str[i] != '\0') ? tmp : "Unknown";
```

Answer (score 5):

**1.** `sch_str[i]` is not a pointer. Cannot compare it with `NULL`.
**2.** Cannot put [assign the value of] `sch_str[i]` into `str`

Comment: Yup. However, this is **not** what the error message is about.

Answer (score 3):

```
(sch_str[i] != NULL)
```

You're testing a character against NULL, you have a logical error.

`sch_str` is a pointer to `char`, therfore `sch_str[i]` is a `char`. `NULL` represetns a null pointer, so this comparison has no sense.

Answer (score 2):

better to use this

```
sch_str[i] != '\0'
```

and one more thing problem is in this whole

```
str = (sch_str[i] != NULL) ? sch_str[i] : "Unknown";
```

try to replace this with this

```
str = (sch_str[i] != '\0') ? "hello": "Unknown";
```

actually you are copying a single character in str when condition is true that is why it showing warning for that

Answer (score 0):

`sch_str[i] != NULL` is a comparison between a character and NULL. You can't do it.
For comparing with NULL it should be a pointer.
`char *sch_str="pqrs";` is a pointer to string `"pqrs"`. Then `sch_str[i]` holds character not total string. You can do it by using `sch_str[i] != '\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to change char *str to const char and then the != '\0'

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char *str = "Error";
    char *sch_str = "pqrs";
    int i=1;

    if (i >= 0)
            str = (sch_str[i] != '\0') ? sch_str : "Unknown";


    printf("%c\n",sch_str[i]);
    printf("%s\n",str);

return 0;
}
```